# R.NET vs R.NET.Community in NuGet

Tags: nuget, r.net

Can anyone tell me the difference between `R.NET` and `R.NET.Community` in the NuGET package manager?  They both reference http://rdotnet.codeplex.com/ as their Project URL.

The old project page says:

> R.NET is now distributed via R.NET.Community on NuGet

does this mean that the `R.NET` package is obsolete and should not be installed?

I'm working on a project that has both `R.NET 1.5.5` and `R.NET.Community 1.6.5` installed. Is it safe to remove `R.NET` and everything should still work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are correct - R.NET was [replaced by R.NET.Community](http://jmp75.github.io/rdotnet/getting_started/#getting-set-up):

> Note that you must uninstall packages dependencies or R.NET 1.5.5 or earlier, if pre-existing. R.NET 1.5.13 uses a different package identifier: R.NET.Community

It's also worth noting that, at the time of writing, R.NET development seems to have stalled, with [the last commit being in August 2015](https://github.com/jmp75/rdotnet/commits/master). The issue/bug list however is growing.

Comment: This info is now outdated. Right now R .Net community only supports legacy versions of R. For the latest version R, install R.NET from Nuget.